# CircuitLab with fixed frequency

Tags: circuitlab

Inspired by this SE question, I was wondering how good CircuitLab would be a solving this type of problem.

[Why do we not include the current source when finding the Thévenin equivalent impedance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478787/)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg2JAi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question asks: what should be the value of an impedance attached to the right side such that the power is maximized. One method to solve is to find the open circuit voltage and divide by the short circuit current.

I got the correct answer eventually, but the process was a bit clunky. **Any tips on a better process?** I am still learning CircuitLab.

I used a frequency of 1 rad/sec (1/2pi Hz) so the impedance for the inductors would match the inductance.

I really only want to run at one frequency, not a range. I used a very narrow range instead. A lot of points per decade are necessary to be sure that a point is within the range (otherwise you get nothing).

At first I was using degrees for Voc and Isc. But the default has limited significant figures and I don't know how to change it. I switched to rads.

After I got the Voc and Isc, I used Excel to divide the two. Then, for the final answer, the imaginary part is inverted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With formulas shown:

[image]

Comment: Tips on a better process requires that the process is revealed. You haven’t really (if at all) revealed it so......

Comment: @Andyaka - I thought that I explained it fairly well, maybe not. I added pictures of graphs. Possible improvements to process: 1) why did I need to run a sweep when I only want one frequency? 2) Is there a way to get the answer directly in CircuitLab without using Excel?

Comment: How about running a transient analysis. I use a different sim so I’m assuming that the term transient analysis translates.

Comment: @Andyaka - Transient analysis = CircuitLab Time Domain. Doesn't work as well, hard to extract the phase information from the graph.